# HTML is disabled by PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a Problem with HTML and PHP
As soon as I add a PHP code to a PHP File, the HTML code disappears.
Its pretty hard to explain.
As example this:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Example</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <span> Hello </span>
      <?php
         echo 'Hi';
      ?>
      <span>Hey</span>
   </body>
</html>
```

It only displays Hello but Hi and Hey disappeard.
When I try it local everything works, this problem came as soon as I uploaded it to a Server.

When I ctrl + U in my Index site, it displays this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Schweizer Quiz"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Jan Ritzl"/>
        <meta name="Six" content="Quiz"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/style.css"/>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/jquery.fullBG.js"></script>
        <title>Quiz Schweiz</title>
    </head>

<body>  
    <img id="background" src="./img/stadt.jpg" style="visibility: hidden" id="background" />
    <script>
        $(window).load( function() {
            $( '#background' ).fullBG();
        } );
    </script>
    <div id="userdaten">
        <a href="./login.php"><img src="./img/six.png" id="logo"/></a>
        <h2>Allgemeinwissen Schweiz</h2>
        <h4>Füllen Sie diese 30 Fragen so gut aus wie nur möglich!<br/>Falls Sie auf eine Frage keine Antwort wissen, schreiben Sie einen "-"</h4> 
        <form action="save.php" METHOD="POST">
        <label for="Name"><span>Name</span></label><input id="Name" name="Name" class="form" type="text" required />
        <label for="Vorname"><span>Vorname</span></label><input id="Vorname" name="Vorname" class="form" type="text" required  />
    </div>

    <div id="fragendiv">
            <label for="f1"><span>1. Wie viele Bundesräte hat die Schweiz?</span></label><input id="f1" name="f1" class="frage" size="100" type="number" required />
            <label for="f2"><span>2. Wie heissen diese Bundesräte?</span></label><input id="f2" name="f2" class="frage" size="100" type="text" required />
            <label for="f3"><span>3. Wie heisst der bekannteste Schweizer Berg?</span></label><input id="f3" name="f3" class="frage" size="100" type="text" required />
            <label for="f4"><span>4. Wie heisst die bekannteste Luzerner Brücke?</span></label><input id="f4" name="f4" class="frage" size="100" type="text" required />
            <label for="f5"><span>5. Wann feiert die Schweiz jeweils ihr Jubiläum?</span></label><input id="f5" name="f5" class="frage" size="100" type="text" required />
            <label for="f6"><span>6. Wie viele Kantone hat die Schweiz?</span></label><input id="f6" name="f6" class="frage" size="100" type="number" required />
```

The Code stops as soon as I use PHP...
Can Someone help me ?

## PHP Info log:

http://www.surf4you.ch/help/logfile.php

Comment: That means PHP is not properly configured on your server. If your code has any errors with error reporting turned off that also does that but that 1 line code doesn't seem to have any error. Check error log

Comment: do you have a live link

Comment: What does the `View-Source` look like?

Comment: Seems like your PHP isn't running.Sometimes your hosting company won't run PHP when the wrong permissions is set on the PHP file. Try Change it to rw-r--r--

Comment: are you also changing the file extension from html to php?

Comment: Link: http://www.surf4you.ch/help/logfile.php

Comment: Have you compared the file permissions on logfile.php and your quiz-file? And the extension is .php?

Answer (score 0):

can you give us more infos ?

For ie, try to create a phpinfo.php file
and inside put only

```
<?php print(phpinfo()); ?>
```

That seems the server is no proper configure and php not woks. See the logs of your server

Answer (score 0):

I think your html code has before like this and now you changed it and it had maked cache in your browser try to use another browser. Or your PHP configurations is not correct. Give us the php info by using this command `<?php print(phpinfo()); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also echo all the HTML code but it is really bad.
Better contact the server admin. Your code is okay.
Can you show us your phpinfo(); ?

Comment: Try setting a header on the top like this in the pho code: header('Content-Type: text/html');

Comment: You can read more about headers here: php.net/manual/en/function.header.php